# why StringBuilder in java acts as equal even the exact string is not same?

Tags: string, stringbuilder

```
import java.io.StringBufferInputStream;
import java.util.*;
public class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("kitayuta");
        StringBuilder a = s.reverse();
        if(a.equals(s)){
            System.out.println("true");
        }
    }
}
```

**the above code prints true as output but i reversed the string how could it be true?**

Comment: Try `s.toString().equals(s.reverse().toString())` instead.

Comment: @S.D. thank you but why this method returns true.what is the reason?

Comment: `StringBuilder.reverse()` [returns the same](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse()) `StringBuilder`, not a string.